# Is it possible to replace an image served with images.get_serving_url and keep the existing urls using AppEngine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine

Let's say a bad photo has been shared but the photo's serving url is cached in many places (without keeping references from each cached serving url to the image)

When it's detected that the photo is a bad photo, if it's replaced with another photo, does the existing serving urls **break** or **point to the new photo** or **keep serving the deleted/replaced photo**?

(When I say replaced, I assume the GCS file is overwritten by another image)

Comment: You cannot replace a blob

Comment: What do you mean by "a blob"?

Comment: You cannot overwite binary data (blob).